# Print Palindrome in Java

Tags: java

I have the following code and i want to print the palindrome on console. Please let me know what should come inside the if condition so that it can print all palindrome in between 0 to 10000.

The palindrome is 161, 1221, 4554, etc....

Java code:

```
int palindrome[];
palindrome = new int[10000];

for (int count = 0; count < palindrome.length; count++ ){
    palindrome[count] = 0;
    if(){
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Smells like homework.  Also you should go back and accept some answers to your earlier questions if you want people to help you.

Comment: fawad, you need some basics put in place.  The fastest way to do so, is to ask your teacher as you may take quite long if you need to figure them out yourself even asking on the net.

Comment: Dear Ravn, i myself is a professional computer engineering having more knowledge in C/C++. So its not a big deal for me to just understand few functions of java. I posted this problem here is just to understand which functions are good to use for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Dude, you're such a liar. If you knew C at all, you could write this function in C and the port to Java would be almost zero effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this might work

```
public boolean isPalindrome(final int num) {
    final String s = Integer.toString(num);
    return s.equals(new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This will do:

```
    if (isPalindrome(count)) {
        System.out.println(count);
    }

...

public boolean isPalindrome(int num) {
    // implement method here (ie: do your homework)
}
```

Comment: Do i have to include any library to call this function?

Comment: Actually, i'm not very good in Java that is why i wanted to know the logic or syntax for that.

Comment: @fawad `Integer.toString()` and `String.charAt()` are all you need to implement it.

Comment: oh thank you so much. Secondly, please let me know which editor can i use for JAVA. That is easily downloadable and compile the JAVA code.

Comment: +1 for a good answer (and also because "NullUserException" is an awesome name!)

Answer (score 3):

You need to transform the number into a string and then check if the string reversed is equal to the original string. This looks a lot like some homework, if so please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: please add the appropriate tag ... What does that mean?

Comment: someone did it for you question like yours are tagged "homework"

Comment: oh but this is not the homework infact. Anywaz, i don't know the syntax of java very well but i'm very good in C/C++ that is why i was taking such help.

Comment: @fawad If you follow aniri suggestion, the could would look identical in C and Java (well, NEARLY identical ;-)).

Comment: Btw, this solution is way faster than reversing a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

The code golf solution:

```
   public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
       return ("" + number).equals(new StringBuilder("" + number).reverse().toString());
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also reverse the number and check if the reversed one and your number are equal.

To reverse the number: keep dividing it with 10 until the result is 0. Save the remainders of the divisions. Starting from the first remainder you get, multiply it by 10 and add the next remainder. Keep multiplying by 10 and adding remainders till you use all the remainders.

Comment: I think that would be easy if i change the integer to string and then reverse the string and match with the original one.
Thanks, your logic is also very appropriate

Answer (score 1):

To revers I use a StringBuffer, StringBuffer(num).reverse().toString();

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints:

a) To get the last digit of a number use the remainder (%) operator

```
Example:
result = number % 10; // 21 % 10 = 1
```

b) To cut of the last digit, divide by 10

```
Example:
number = number / 10; // 21 / 10 = 2;
```

c) Multiply the result by 10

```
Example:
result = result * 10; // 1 * 10 = 10
```

d) Repeat until some condition is fulfilled (shouldn't be too hard to figure out ;-))

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean isPalin(int n)
{
 String s = Integer.toString(n);
 return s.equals( new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString() );
}
```

so your if condition should contain: `isPalin(count)`

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean isPalin(int n)
{
 int nn = 0, tmp = n;
 while(n > 0)
 {
    nn = nn*10 + n%10;
    n /= 10;
 }
 return tmp==nn;
}
```

I prefer doing it this way instead of using strings, since strings make the process slow as it involves a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestFinal {
    public static Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String original ,reverse ="";
        // TODO, add your application code
        System.out.println("Enter the text!");
        original = c.next();
        int length = original.length();

        for(int i =length - 1;i >= 0;i--)
            reverse = reverse +original.charAt(i);
            if(original.equals(reverse))
                System.out.println("entered strig is a palindrome");
            else
                System.out.println("the text is not a palindrome");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use the code marker to mark everything as code. This will help the readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to print palindrome:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String A=sc.next();

        /* Enter your code here. Print output to STDOUT. */

        int len = A.length();
        String B ="";
        for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--){
            B=B+A.charAt(i);
        }

        if(A.equals(B))
            System.out.println("Yes");
        else
            System.out.println("No");

    }
}
```